# Binding data frames stored in a list in R

Tags: r, plyr, rbind, do.call

I have several data frames stored in R memory among several other objects.
Their particularity is that they are all named as "Station_Year.df".
I want to merge all these data frames into one.

I tried:

```
df_list <- ls(pattern=".df")
dataset <- rbind(df_list)
```

But I get a data frame with the names of the data frames...

Comment: use reshape, cbind, and rbind to do what you wish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mget` to get the data of each dataframe of the df_list. So you can do:

```
dataset <- do.call(rbind, mget(df_list))
```

Note that this implies that all the rows are of the same length. Probably you find useful also the `merge` function.
Thanks alexis_laz, I forgot the do.call.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `do.call(rbind, mget(.))`?